# Tradingview: Time index in if loop

Tags: pine-script

Consider two indicators, s1 and s2 in an if statement such that:

if s1 > s2
   do something (buy)

I want to include an additional condition to follow the initial if statement such that buy is initiated only 'if' s1 and s2 increase in price over 'n' consecutive time intervals. Any suggestions please?

My code: Buy signal to be activated if: s1 > s2 and s2 > s3 and s3 > s4 AND then if s1 consecutively increases over 't1' time intervals.

```
var t1 = 0
go_long = 0
if s1 > s2 and s2 > s3 and s3 > s4
    if t1 == 2
        if s1 > s1[t1] 
            go_long := 1
    else
        t1 := t1 + 1
strategy.entry("long",strategy.long,ordersize,when=go_long)
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to solve this is to add another variable you increment in every location.

Then you'd need an if where you check for variable equals n.

Answer (score 0):

This is always keeping current the number of consecutive increases of `s1` in variable `s1Ups`, as was suggested in previous answer. The test for the minimum required or greater has been added to your `go_long` condition and you can vary the required minimum in the indicator's *Settings/Inputs*:

```
t1 = input(2, "Consecutive increases required")
var s1Ups = 0
s1Ups := change(s1) > 0 ? s1Ups + 1 : 0
go_long = s1 > s2 and s2 > s3 and s3 > s4 and s1Ups >= t1
strategy.entry("long",strategy.long,ordersize,when=go_long)
```